# How to save python file in jupyter note if path contains spaces %20

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

When I try to save a file in a jupyter notebook I get an error saying there is no file or directory.

### Error Message ___________________________________________________________
Unexpected error while saving file: OneDrive%%20-%%20Files/Desktop/PythonProjects/bhp.ipynb [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\username\OneDrive%%20-%%20Files\Desktop\PythonProjects\bhp.ipynb'

I began having this problem after a software update where now I can only save things to "OneDrive - Files".  Unfortunately, the path to OneDrive contains several spaces - causing this error every time I try to save a new file.  I would use a different directory if I could.  I was hoping for an easy fix like wrapping the path in quotes - but so far this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the %20 characters with a literal space resolved the issue.  I suppose the Jupyter Notebook treats the path the same way as a url and inserts %20 characters for spaces.  But when saving to a directory on a pc - the %20 characters can be replaced with a space - without the need to wrap the path in quotations or to place backslashes before the spaces.